# Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to a sql server in my asp.net application. I have given connection string in my web.config as follows :

I am getting following error while running the application :

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

If i use remote server's ip address as data source in connection string, I get following error
"Login falied for user 'sa'"

I researched and found some ports need to be opened between the server and my machine, which I got done by network team, still the same issue. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly. you need to have `TCP/IP enabled` and configured the `TCP/IP Ports` on sql server configuration manager at remote server.

you need to have TCP/IP connectivity .Just launch it, enter the DNS host name or IP address in the Server Name' box and hit Connect. The hosting company needs to have enabling TCP/IP on your SQL Server instance, and them providing you with secure access to the IP address that instance is running on.

Most administrators do not allow direct access to the SQL Server from outside the firewall. In that case, if you can connect to the host over VPN then you should be able to connect directly to the server with Enterprise Manager or SQL Management Studio.

Please go through it [Configurations-Remote-Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you porting code from [Hypersonic](http://hsqldb.org) or [H2](http://www.h2database.com)? If so, the username `sa` won't work.